# Adding animation to a List View in Android

Tags: android, android-animation

I want to animate the items of the list view. At Present i am applying the Transition Animation on the list items whenever new items are added. But this is not the animation i want to achieve. I want that when a new item is added in the list view at that time the whole List view move a place down to make way for the newly added item.

Currently the code i am using is :

```
set = new AnimationSet(true);

    animation = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
    animation.setDuration(50);
    set.addAnimation(animation);

    animation = new TranslateAnimation(
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, -1.0f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f
    );
    animation.setDuration(150);
    set.addAnimation(animation);

    LayoutAnimationController controller = new LayoutAnimationController(set, 1.0f);
    l.setLayoutAnimation(controller);
    l.setAdapter(listAdaptor);
```

And then while adding items through button onClick

```
    l.startLayoutAnimation();
```

Any other suggestions to achieve such animation.